# How to makematplotlib fully plot functions that evaluate to complex values AND maintain plot styling?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

I am trying to build an application that can plot a variety of input functions. For functions that evaluate to complex values at certain values of x, matplotlib will omit those portions in the final plot. For example, for the function y=(2*x + 1)**(1/3)-(2*x - 1)**(1/3), which results in a bell curve, MPL only plots values greater than .5, the rest of the values are set to NaN. [Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8MqJ.png) versus [Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkBJy.png).

I have tried using plot_implicit() from spb which does plot the full bell curve, but then omits any styling such as line color which is important for the application I'm working on. I have previously tried adding a Nan value handler (did not save) involving np.real/imaginary to no avail.

Minimal Reproducible Example: The following code will correctly plot the bell curve, but then the cmap coloring will do nothing. If adaptive =False, the coloring will be present but then the full function is not plotted

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from spb import plot_implicit


qVal = '(2*x + 1)^(1/3)-(2*x - 1)^(1/3)'
qVal = qVal.replace('^', '**')
cmap = ListedColormap(["red"],"#ffffff00")
x, y = symbols('x y')
lhs = y
rhs = qVal
rhs = formattedQ = eval(rhs)
plot = plot_implicit(Eq(lhs, rhs),  (x, -5, 5),
    (y, -5, 5),adaptive=True,show=True, rendering_kw={"cmap": cmap})
```

Comment: If the y value is imaginary, what do you actually want to plot? The magnitude of y? The real part of y? Why not just ask for that (for example, plot `abs(y)` instead of just plotting y)

Comment: @ThePhoton yes I want to plot the real part of Y should there be a real/imaginary part.

Comment: Then just set `qVal = 're((2*x + 1)**(1/3)-(2*x - 1)**(1/3))'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it appears that the application you are developing involves parsing user inputs. I guess you'd have to work harder on the parser :)

Let's start with your parsing:

```py
qVal = '(2*x + 1)^(1/3)-(2*x - 1)^(1/3)'
qVal = qVal.replace('^', '**')
rhs = qVal
rhs = formattedQ = eval(rhs)
print(rhs)
# out: -(2*x - 1)**0.333333333333333 + (2*x + 1)**0.333333333333333
```

When Python sees `1/3`, it evaluates it to `0.333333333333333`, which is a floating point number. If your application needs to further apply some symbolic computation, generally it would be better to replace floating point numbers with rational numbers, which are exact. You would have to to modify the input string to replace `(1/3)` with `Rational(1,3)`: this way you wouldn't lose precision.

Now to the problem of this question: the above expression, `rhs`, represents complex roots which of course have imaginary and real parts. The plotting module is only going to show you the real part.

So, you would have to parse your input string to replace `(1/3)` with sympy's `real_root` function. In the following code I'm going to show the differences:

```py
x = symbols("x")
expr1 = (2*x + 1)**(S(1)/3)-(2*x - 1)**(S(1)/3)
expr2 = real_root((2*x + 1), 3) - real_root((2*x - 1), 3)
print("expr1: ", expr1)
print("expr2: ", expr2)
plot((expr2, "expr2"), (expr1, "expr1"), (x, -4, 4))
# out:
# expr1:  -(2*x - 1)**(1/3) + (2*x + 1)**(1/3)
# expr2:  -Piecewise((Abs(2*x - 1)**(1/3)*sign(2*x - 1), Eq(im(x), 0)), ((2*x - 1)**(1/3), True)) + Piecewise((Abs(2*x + 1)**(1/3)*sign(2*x + 1), Eq(im(x), 0)), ((2*x + 1)**(1/3), True))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For some reason when I use the same code that you provided, the bell shaped curve is correct but it is plotting the bottom half of the curve in the negative y

Comment: I've released a new version of the module today. Try updating, repeat the process and let me know.