# Matplotlib only plotting half of a complex function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sympy

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75851180/how-to-makematplotlib-fully-plot-functions-that-evaluate-to-complex-values-and-m/75855074#75855074) answer I was able to fully plot complex functions like y=(2*x + 1)**(1/3)-(2*x - 1)**(1/3), where previously only half the plot was showing. However, when I try to plot another complex function like x^(2/3) + y^(2/3) = 4^(2/3) which should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUaC8.png),
I end up only getting [half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pBfr.png) of the graph.

When I try using real_root() like I did for the other function, I end up getting this error

```
All-NaN axis encountered
  y_max = np.nanmax([self._bbox[1][1], y], axis=0)
[half][2] of the actual plot.
```

I have also tried using adaptive = True/False, as well as plot_implicit instead of plot which still resulted in only half of the plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import spb 
import regex


def queryMatplotlibEq(qVal):
    x, y = symbols('x y', real= True)
    lhs, rhs = qVal.split('=')
    lhs = eval(lhs)
    rhs = eval(rhs)
    expr = lhs - rhs
    sols = solve(expr, y)
    spb.plot(*sols, (x, -10, 10), {"color": "teal"},legend=False, aspect="equal",xlim=(-5,5), ylim=(-5, 5), show=True, adaptive=True,n=10000,is_point=True)

#THIS WORKS
# qVal="y=(2*x + 1)**(1/3)-(2*x - 1)**(1/3)"
# qVal="y=real_root((2*x + 1), 3) - real_root((2*x - 1), 3)"


#THIS DOESN'T
qVal="x**(2/3) + y**(2/3) = 4**(2/3)"
# qVal="real_root((x**2),3) + real_root((y**2),3) = real_root(16,3)"

queryMatplotlibEq(qVal)
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Matplotlib, other than sympy uses it as a backend, so it’s strange that you have put it in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `solve` is unable to find all solutions. But in this case, you can get away with `plot_implicit`.

```py
from sympy import *
from spb import *
x, y = symbols("x, y")
expr = real_root(x**2, 3) + real_root(y**2, 3) - real_root(16, 3)
plot_implicit(expr)
```

[image]

Note that if you use `x, y = symbols("x, y", real=True)`, the evaluation will be even faster.